# Sortable html table of integers with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, html-table

I seek help sorting a html table which only contains numbers in the range 0-100, my current attempts have all been in javascript, however, it does not have to be done in javascript. The problem is seemingly that it sorts the table data as strings since it would sort 8, 59 and 1 in this order: 1, 59, 8 where I would like it to be sorted as 1, 8, 59.
The code I have used is one from w3schools:

```
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("Tabellen");
  switching = true;
  dir = "asc";
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      switchcount ++;
    } else {
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This would work fine if I was trying to sort letters, however, that is not the case.
I have also tried the following solution:

```
var collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {numeric: true});
var myArray = ['8', '69', '1'];
console.log(myArray.sort(collator.compare));
```

which I found on a similar post to my own, and this works fine on it's own, however, I cannot figure out how to incorporate it into the w3schools code to get it to work.

Comment: Compare them like this: `+x.textContent > +y.textContent` (the `+` turns a string into a number). Final note: [please do not use w3schools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com).

Comment: try doing this `arr.sort((a,b)=> Number(a)-Number(b))`

Answer (score 0):

you can first convert the string to a number and then sort it.

```js
var myArr = ['8', '69', '1'];

var sortedArray = myArr
    .map(function(item) {
        return Number(item);
    })
    .sort(function(a, b){
        return a-b;
    });

console.log(sortedArray); // prints [1, 8, 69]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm afraid my lack of programming knowledge means that I'm not quite sure how I would go about implementing that into the first code i posted in my original post, I appreciate you taking the time to write an answer for me though :).

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortTable(columnNum){
// ref : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp
var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
table = document.getElementById(this.props.id);
switching = true;
dir = "asc"; 
while (switching) {
  switching = false;
  rows = table.rows;
  for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
    shouldSwitch = false;
    x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[columnNum];
    y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[columnNum];
    x = x.textContent.toLowerCase();
    y = y.textContent.toLowerCase();
    let xInt = parseInt(x);
    let yInt = parseInt(y);
    if (dir === "asc") {
      if(x === xInt.toString() && y === yInt.toString()){
        if (xInt > yInt) { shouldSwitch= true;break; }
      }else{ if (x > y) { shouldSwitch= true;break; } }
    } else if (dir === "desc") {
      if(x === xInt.toString() && y === yInt.toString()){
        if (xInt < yInt) { shouldSwitch= true;break; }
      }else{ if (x < y) { shouldSwitch= true;break; } }
    }
    // console.log(x,y)
  }
  if (shouldSwitch) {
    rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
    switching = true;
    switchcount ++;      
  } else {
    if (switchcount === 0 && dir === "asc") { dir = "desc"; switching = true; }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Please explain what you have changed.

Answer (score 0):

to convert string to integer in JavaScript you will need to use
parseInt();

So the easiest way to use W3Schools code, would be simply adding parseInt when the variables is used to be compared

Below will be the modified version

```
function sortTable() {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
     //start by saying there should be no switching:
     shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[1];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[1];
      //check if the two rows should switch place:
      if (parseInt(x.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) > 
 parseInt(y.innerHTML.toLowerCase())) {
        //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
         shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
       }
     }
     if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
```